# Where to find in what standard (ISO C, SUS, POSIX) and what version of it a particular C header or function is defined?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, standards

Sometimes I need to write a low level multiplatform C/C++ code so preprocessor environment macroses come in handy. But is there some method or a single internet resource or a place in man where I can easily find a standard where a particular Unix API was first introduced to use a particular macro definition in my code allowing the usage of that API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man is your friend. My linux distribution has all POSIX definitions as man pages. E.g

```
man 3p printf
```

gives me the POSIX definition, whereas

```
man 3 printf
```

gives me the linux specific version.

To search for all POSIX stuff my strategy is to enter

> opengroup name-of-function

in my prefered search engine.

For ISO C you find the standards easily online (well oficially these are drafts). The current C standard, C11, is n1570.pdf, you should find it through that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the man pages.

For example, [`man 3 printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) says:

> Conforming To
>
> The fprintf(), printf(), sprintf(), vprintf(), vfprintf(), and vsprintf() functions conform to C89 and C99. The snprintf() and vsnprintf() functions conform to C99.

And [`man 2 open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open):

> Conforming to
>
> SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.